# how to implement both horizontal and vertical scrolling in page control in ios

Tags: ios5, uipagecontrol

I have different views and also page control.the horizontal scrolling is working by sliding the views.Now i want to implement vertical scrolling in each view how to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * NumberOfPages, 1);
```

Comment: Could you enhance this answer to explain how/why this might work?

Comment: [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)]; put values in height as much u want vertical scrolling